# Simple way to synchronously execute code after setTimout() code is done

Tags: javascript, settimeout, synchronous

I need a simple way to wait for setTimeout code to finish executing and then run the code that comes after setTimeout.
Now the code after loop containing setTimout is executing before loop/setTimout is finished executing.

```
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(i);
  }, i*1000);
 }
console.log("loop/timeout is done executing");
```

Comment: That's not how `setTimeout` works. See [Asynchronous vs synchronous execution, what does it really mean?](//stackoverflow.com/q/748175)

Comment: Do you want *all* of the timeouts to complete first?

Comment: yes whole for loop then code bellow it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setTimeout` is by definition not synchronous - whatever you use to solve the issue will *have* to be asynchronous, there's no way around that.

The best way to achieve something like this is to use `Promise`s instead, calling `Promise.all` on an array of the created promises:

```js
(async () => {
  await Promise.all(Array.from(
    { length: 5 },
    (_, i) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(i);
      res();
    }, i * 1000))
  ));
  console.log("loop/timeout is done executing");
})();
```

Although `await` is awaiting a Promise, and Promises aren't synchronous, if you're want the code to *look* flat so you can have the final `console.log` on the same indentation level as the main function block, this is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

you can define a function and call that function inside the timeout

```js
    let currentForId = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(i);
        if(++currentForId == 5)
        calling("message");
      }, i*1000);
     }


    function calling(msg){
       console.log(msg);
       console.log("loop/timeout is done executing");
    }
```

Comment: do you want all the timeouts to complete before printing ??

Comment: yeah, now you'll be calling `calling` 5 times - again, not what was asked :p

Comment: yes I like the simplicity of your answer but I want call the calling only once after the  loop is done.

Comment: now you have one callback after all the timeouts iterated

Answer (score 0):

The code/message you need to run at the end of the count needs to be inside the for loop.  Here's a simple way to achieve this.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(i);
        if (i == 4) {
            console.log("loop/timeout is done executing");
        }
    }, i * 1000);
}
```